# not getting building number from google place autocomplete response

Tags: autocomplete

I am using Google places API to auto-complete addresses using javascript.

When I type an address starting with street_number, I get multiple matching option in the list. When I check the result from address_component after selecting one of the entries from the suggestion list, I do not get street_number always. I get other information correct like city, state, country and Zip.

For example I am using "678 Old Sherman Turnpike Danbury, CT, United States" in my search field, I do not get the number 678 in my response, while other information are correctly fine.

If I use "77 Central Golf Link Road, Golf Links, New Delhi, India" then I get the street_number perfectly fine along with other field info.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!!